# Tricky GROUP BY issue on ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m currently facing an issue that my Oracle knowledge cannot solve, I’m definitely not DB expert and that’s why I ask you if you have any idea how to solve my SQL query issue.

Here’s my problem, I have two tables, let’s call them DEVICE_TABLE and COUNT_TABLE

COUNT_TABLE looks like :

```
    DEVICE (Int) PK         |       QUANTITY (Int)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        1001                |              4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        1002                |             20
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        1003                |              1
…
```

DEVICE_TABLE looks like :

```
     ID (Int) PK            |      WiFi (String)            |     Email (String)          |   Bluetooth(String)           |   …
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        1001                |             Yes               |               No            |                 No            |   …
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        1002                |             Yes               |               Yes           |                 No            |   …
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        1003                |             Unknown           |               Unknown       |                 Yes           |   …
…
```

Constraints are :

DEVICE_TABLE.ID = COUNT_TABLE.DEVICE

WiFi, Email, Bluetooth… are Strings that can only be : “Yes”, “No” or “Unknown”

Finally, my SQL request result expected is  (based on my example):

```
         Feature        |            Yes           |              No            |            Unknown          
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        WiFi            |             24           |                 0          |                 1                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
       Email            |             20           |                 4          |                 1                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Bluetooth           |              1           |                24          |                 0                   
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
…
```

In few words, aim of this request is to sum all devices count that are compatible with a particular feature.

Thank you in advance if you have any clue on how to achieve this ! (Maybe it is not possible…)

Comment: `COUNT_TABLE looks like :` ... why didn't you just post the SQL create and insert statements? It's so much easier to read.

Comment: Yep, right I will publish it if no one founds a solution to ease testing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle 11, you can use the `pivot` clause together with the `unpivot` clause:

```
with 
count_table as (
     select 1001 device_id,  4 quantity from dual union all
     select 1002 device_id, 20 quantity from dual union all
     select 1003 device_id,  1 quantity from dual 
),
device_table as (
     select 1001 id, 'Yes'     wifi, 'No'       email, 'No'  bluetooth from dual union all
     select 1002 id, 'Yes'     wifi, 'Yes'      email, 'No'  bluetooth from dual union all
     select 1003 id, 'Unknown' wifi, 'Unknown'  email, 'Yes' bluetooth from dual 
)
----------------------------------------
select * from (
      select
        feature,
        yes_no_unknown,
        sum(quantity)  quantity
      from 
         count_table  c join 
         device_table d on c.device_id = d.id
      unpivot  ( yes_no_unknown
                 for feature in (wifi, email, bluetooth)
      ) 
      group by 
      feature,
      yes_no_unknown
)  
pivot ( sum (quantity)
        for yes_no_unknown in ('Yes' as yes, 'No' as no, 'Unknown' as unknown)
)
;
```

Alternatively, you might want to join the two existing tables to a third table that containts the values for the three desired rows. It's probably a bit easier to read, too:

```
with 
count_table as (
     select 1001 device_id,  4 quantity from dual union all
     select 1002 device_id, 20 quantity from dual union all
     select 1003 device_id,  1 quantity from dual 
),
device_table as (
     select 1001 id, 'Yes'     wifi, 'No'       email, 'No'  bluetooth from dual union all
     select 1002 id, 'Yes'     wifi, 'Yes'      email, 'No'  bluetooth from dual union all
     select 1003 id, 'Unknown' wifi, 'Unknown'  email, 'Yes' bluetooth from dual 
)
----------------------------------------
select
   f.txt,
   sum(case when ( f.txt = 'wifi'      and d.wifi      = 'Yes' ) or
                 ( f.txt = 'email'     and d.email     = 'Yes' ) or
                 ( f.txt = 'bluetooth' and d.bluetooth = 'Yes' ) 
            then   c.quantity
            else   0 end
      ) yes,
   sum(case when ( f.txt = 'wifi'      and d.wifi      = 'No' ) or
                 ( f.txt = 'email'     and d.email     = 'No' ) or
                 ( f.txt = 'bluetooth' and d.bluetooth = 'No' ) 
            then   c.quantity
            else   0 end
      ) no,
   sum(case when ( f.txt = 'wifi'      and d.wifi      = 'Unknown' ) or
                 ( f.txt = 'email'     and d.email     = 'Unknown' ) or
                 ( f.txt = 'bluetooth' and d.bluetooth = 'Unknown' ) 
            then   c.quantity
            else   0 end
      ) unknown
from 
   count_table  c                                   join 
   device_table d on c.device_id = d.id     cross   join
   (
        select 'wifi'      txt from dual union all
        select 'email'     txt from dual union all
        select 'bluetooth' txt from dual
   ) f
group by 
    f.txt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it, I got already 3 answers but yours seem to be most optimized (at least I hope)

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to please you - your db design is far from perfect in terms of relative db.
The only possible way is to use UNION:

```
select 'WiFi' as Feature, (select count(*) from  DEVICE_TABLE where WiFi = 'Yes') as Yes, (select count(*) from  DEVICE_TABLE where WiFi = 'No') as No 
union
select 'Email' as Feature, (select count(*) from  DEVICE_TABLE where Email = 'Yes') as Yes, (select count(*) from  DEVICE_TABLE where Email = 'No') as No 
...
```

Comment: I agree about wrong datamodel design, but unfortunately I cannot change it :/
I was thinking about this, but I fear that it is not so optimized (need to parse X times my device table where X is the number of different features)

Answer (score 1):

1) Data model could probably be improved, by creating a device capability table that would have device ID, references DEVICE_TABLE.ID and Capability.

Where you have Yes in the device table enter a row into device capability, and get rid of the feature/capability columns from device table.

Barring that:

```
with Capabilities as (
  select  ID, 'WiFi' as capability, Wifi as has_capability
  from    device_table
  union all 
  select  ID, 'Email', Email 
  from    device_table
  union all 
  select  ID, 'BlueTooth', BlueTooth
  from    device_table
)    
select  C.capability
        , sum(case when C.has_capability = 'Yes' then CNT.quantity end) as Yes
        , sum(case when C.has_capability = 'No' then CNT.quantity end) as No
from    device_table D
        inner join Capabilities C on C.ID = D.ID
        left outer join count_table CNT on CNT.DEVICE = D.ID
group by 
        C.capability
order by 
        C.capability
```

Comment: Yes I know that my datamodel is not right. But unfortunately it's the one that I need to use... I cannot change it (customer is always king... even if he's wrong !)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Oracle 11g, Pivot feature can be used to get the solution.Please refer the below query :

```
select features,nvl(yes,0) yes,nvl(no,0) no,nvl(unknown,0) unknown from (
select * from (select 'Wifi' as features,wifi,nvl(quantity,0) quantity from count_table, device_table where id = device_id)
pivot (sum(nvl(quantity,0)) for Wifi in ('Yes' as yes,'No' as no,'Unknown' as unknown))
Union all
select * from (select 'Bluetooth' as features,bluetooth,nvl(quantity,0) quantity from count_table, device_table where id = device_id)
pivot (sum(nvl(quantity,0)) for bluetooth in ('Yes' as yes,'No' as no,'Unknown' as unknown))
union all
select * from (select 'Email' as features,Email,nvl(quantity,0) quantity from count_table, device_table where id = device_id)
pivot (sum(nvl(quantity,0)) for Email in ('Yes' as yes,'No' as no,'Unknown' as unknown))
)
order by yes desc
```

Refer to SQLFiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97793/1/0